# mySQL administrator (Ubuntu 11) - can't log in to gui with same root credentials I use at command line

Tags: mysql

I can log in at the command line -
mysql -uroot -p******** (my password is replaced by ***'s)
but when I try those credentials in the mySQL administrator gui I get `Could not connect to host 'castleLinux2011'.
MySQL Error Nr. 2003
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'castleLinux2011' (111)

I am doing this locally on my own personal machine.
Using port 3306
Using my local machine name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if you are trying to connect to a remote MySQL server or one running locally on your machine. Information like that is helpful! So, here's the rundown on how to achieve either working correctly:

If you are running the MySQL server *locally* (meaning the machine you are using MySQL administrator on is the same one that is running the server), you want to put "127.0.0.1" into the server host field. The default port that MySQL uses is 3306 - so unless you have changed that, it should work.

If you are running the MySQL server *remotely* (meaning the machine you are using MySQL administrator on is NOT the same one that is running the server), you want to put the IP of the host machine into the server host field. You will have to log in at the command line like you would normally and use the following commands:

```
mysql> update db set Host='your_ip' where Db='your_db_name';
mysql> update user set Host='your_ip' where user='your_user_name';
```

You should replace 'your_ip' with your MySQL administrator machine's IP (like '203.56.81.167') and do the same with your database name and username. This allows sets up the permission for remote connecting securely. You would need to repeat this for all machines and users that would be connecting remotely.

Aside from that, you may also have to expose port 3306 on the host machine's router, firewall, etc. Post another question if you need help with that and provide information about operating system, firewall software, and router manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks Mitch!  I'll start by updating the q with some of that.

Comment: YES! 127.0.0.1 fixed it.  I had been using my actual machine name.  Didn't think 127.0.0.1 would work for a non-web product but it did! Thanks!  Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the GUI should be connecting to localhost not castleLinux2011

Comment: yes that was it

Answer (score 0):

There are some very good suggestions at [Causes of Access-Denied Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html), and I'd be having a close look at the first three suggestions (port types, startup networking config and firewall). Otherwise, check that your `GRANT` rules for the root user do indeed permit connections from locations other than localhost. You might also find [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713429/remote-mysql-access) illuminating